# Examine a type at runtime

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function that can tell me if a type passed there can be undefined:

```
type Person = { name: string, address: string | undefined }
type A = Person['address']

const isUndefinedTyped = <T,>(): boolean => { throw Error('not implemented') }

isUndefined<Person>() // false
isUndefined<A>()      // true
```

Or to put it another way, I want Typescript to inline some compile-time information at runtime.

I've found in TypeScript Design Goals document that:

> Provide additional runtime functionality or libraries. Instead, use TypeScript to describe existing libraries

...is not a goal. I'm not sure if I read it right and what I'm trying to do is simply not possible

---

Just as an example in Scala 3, we can achieve this with following code:

```
import scala.compiletime.summonFrom

trait IsNull[A] { }

object IsNull:
  given [A]: IsNull[Option[A]] = new IsNull[Option[A]] { }
  given IsNull[Null] = new IsNull[Null] { }

  inline def check[A]: Boolean =
    summonFrom {
      case given IsNull[A] => true
      case _ => false
    }

println(IsNull.check[Option[String]])  // true
println(IsNull.check[Option[Int]])     // true
println(IsNull.check[Int])             // false
```

Comment: Types are not persisted in runtime so ist's not possible in the way that you described it. You can have a function that will tell you if current value is undefined (`variable === undefined`) but it's not possible to determine in runtime whether typescript type was defined as union with undefined. What do you want to accomplish? Maybe there's other way to resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianKokot. I guess it's also called type erasure? But I thought there's something like inlining stage in some compilers.

I asked this mostly out of curiosity, but here's a practical problem I had the other day - I wanted to write a generic react component for a form and when above `Person` is passed - the component would render the `name` as required input and `address` as optional input (which must happen at run-time)

Comment: It's not necessarily type erasure - typescript is a superset of javascript, javascript doesn't have types so when typescript is translated to javascrpit, types are removed because this concept doesn't exist in desired language. I'm afraid that without some extra information that is persisted in runtime you won't be able to accomplish this required/optional functionality. The goal of typescript is to improve development by adding types to provide compile-time checks, but it doesn't affect runtime. You could define object of `Person` with `undefined` in optional fields and then use that.

Comment: I can write an example in the answers if you are interested in runtime solution to the optional/required fields. But it's impossible using only types.

Comment: No thanks, but I would accept "impossible" as an answer if you're certain.